# Does Minitube have automatic playlist?

Tags: minitube

I'm using Minitube 2.1, and I was under the impression that it has it had an automatic playlist. Do you have to enable that feature or what?

Comment: It is unticked. After the end of a video, it replays.

Comment: I'm using the version 2.1 from the Center.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, actually the Ubuntu Software Center has 2 versions. The 2.1 version is in the paid section. See my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and is solved in version 2.1.1, additionally you need to run

```
sudo apt-get remove phonon-backend-gstreamer
```

because minitube now uses phonon-backend-vlc.

source: http://flavio.tordini.org/forums/topic/videos-repeat-endlessly-ubuntu-12-04-minitube-2-1

Comment: I hope this is a temporary workaround, because I think it is very bad practice to have to uninstall a package to get another package working. For example what if you're on Kubuntu? Then `phonon-backend-gstreamer` is actually a dependency of the `kubuntu-desktop` package. I have put this remark on the forum thread I linked to.